# Issues with exe compiled Kivy programs accessing images

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller

So I've created a simple program that replaces the slider cursor background with a custom image and tried to compile it using `PyInstaller` using the `-F` argument (to compile it into a single exe). Compilation was successful, but when I tried to execute it, it failed to load the image with the following error log:

```
[WARNING           ] [Image       ] Unable to load image <rogue.jpg>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 822, in _build_canvas
   File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 362, in kivy.graphics.instruction
s.VertexInstruction.source.__set__ (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:7177)
   File "kivy\graphics\context_instructions.pyx", line 381, in kivy.graphics.con
text_instructions.BindTexture.source.__set__ (kivy\graphics\context_instructions
.c:7309)
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 528, in __init__
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 716, in _set_filename
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 432, in load
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 200, in __init__

   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 41, in load
 Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "untitled-1.py", line 21, in <module>
     TestApp().run()
   File "site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
   File "untitled-1.py", line 19, in build
     return MySlider()
   File "site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 321, in __init__
   File "site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 447, in apply
   File "site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 502, in _apply_rule
   File "site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 827, in _build_canvas
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 7:
 ...
       5:            pos: (self.value_pos[0] - sp(16), self.center_y - sp(17)) i
f self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (self.center_x - (16), self.value_pos[1]
 - sp(16))
       6:            size: (sp(32), sp(32))
 >>    7:            source: 'rogue.jpg'
 ...
 Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
   File "site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 822, in _build_canvas
   File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 362, in kivy.graphics.instruction
s.VertexInstruction.source.__set__ (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:7177)
   File "kivy\graphics\context_instructions.pyx", line 381, in kivy.graphics.con
text_instructions.BindTexture.source.__set__ (kivy\graphics\context_instructions
.c:7309)
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 528, in __init__
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 716, in _set_filename
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 432, in load
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 200, in __init__
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 41, in load

Failed to execute script untitled-1
```

What I found interesting is that the program worked just fine if I removed the `rogue.jpg` image from the cwd. It just gave me a blank white Rectangle.
But why did the first case give an error and the second one did not? And how can I prevent it?

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68eOg.jpg) and the source code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Slider>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: (self.value_pos[0] - sp(16), self.center_y - sp(17)) if self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (self.center_x - (16), self.value_pos[1] - sp(16))
            size: (sp(32), sp(32))
            source: 'rogue.jpg'
''')

class MySlider(Slider):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MySlider()

TestApp().run()
```

The compiled .exe file for Python 3.4, Kivy v1.9.2-dev0, Windows can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByA_-5jq6vEYaENGV05oUGU2d2s).

Comment: So the builder gives up,,aybe because of the values tthat are calculated for pos and size in Rectangle of canvas (inside the string provided to the loader)? What are the values for x, y, width and height (i guess)? Valid integers / floats?

Comment: @Dilettant The code works fine. If I run the .py file, everything works as it should. Therefore, values are valid. There is something wrong with the compiled file trying to access the image

Comment: Try to check paths and working directory, whether script can find a file.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky The `.py` script that is located in the same directory is able to locate the file successfully

Comment: Try to print `cwd` from script - may be it changes it to some internal folder? 
What folders are in environment? https://kivy.org/docs/guide/environment.html

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky no, the cwd stays as expected

Comment: kivy environment? are there such folders?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky I've never dealt with them before, what should I look for?

Comment: I can't find the `rogue.jpg` in your unpacked executable.  I expect that PyInstaller has failed to detect the image file and so not packaged it up correctly in the first place.  It might therefore help if you shared what you were doing with PyInstaller and how that compares to https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html.  In particular, have you used the hooks to pull in your required image file?

Comment: @PeterBrittain it's not in there. It's just an external file that is located in the same directory as the executable. That's why I provided a link to the image. No, I haven't been using any hooks or following the tutorial you've provided

Comment: Please look at link in my comment.

Comment: So - you're deliberately trying to access a binary (image) file that has not been packaged up inside your executable...  Why?  Doesn't that break the whole point of using PyInstaller to package it all up?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky It's not quite clear how this applies to my situation, I'd highly appreciate some explanation

Comment: @PeterBrittain the reason why I'm packaging this app is so that it could run on any machine that might not have Python and/or Kivy installed

Comment: You're missing my point.  I totally understand why people use PyInstaller.  What I'm questioning is why you want to use it and yet __not__ package up all your images too.

Comment: @PeterBrittain well, I didn't know there was a way to pack the image as well, so I just took the most obvious path

Comment: So...  Do you see the same issue if you package up your image file too?  If not, I'd suggest that this is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one "sp" in your image source code whatever that is :-)

Instead of:

```
pos: (self.value_pos[0] - sp(16), self.center_y - sp(17)) if self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (self.center_x - (16), self.value_pos[1] - sp(16))
```

Try this:

```
pos: (self.value_pos[0] - sp(16), self.center_y - sp(17)) if self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (self.center_x - sp(16), self.value_pos[1] - sp(16))
```

Or "backslash" formatted (at least here to not scroll too far to the right just to see):

```
pos: (self.value_pos[0] - sp(16), self.center_y - sp(17))\
    if self.orientation == 'horizontal'\
    else (self.center_x - sp(16), self.value_pos[1] - sp(16))
```

Comment: That's interesting. I copied the canvas desription from the Kivy's GitHub repo, and it looks like it's them, who's missing it. I'll report it

Comment: Also, it does not seem to fix the issue

Comment: I am not experienced with kivy magic, so maybe the following is not helpful: WHen the Builder loads your string, the `source` fields value, is it ok to be just a filename, or does it need an anchor, i.e. a special relative (depending from where the "builder" assumes to search/resolve or absolute path?

Comment: No, the path is relative to the cwd (where the source code is located). The code works fine without compilation, if I just run the .py code